# запуск скриптов на виртуальной машине виндовс посредством jenkins

Tags: windows, powershell, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

В среде vSphere создано огромное количество виртуальных машин на базе виндовс 10. Среди них есть jenkins сервер. Вход на vsphere только с VPN. Необходимо при билде jenkins-job запускать PowerShell скрипт на определенной виртуальной машине (как я понимаю имя/ip, креды входа виртуальной машины можно использовать как переменные). Пожалуйста, объясните непросвященному каким образом происходит подключение к vsphere, к ОПРЕДЕЛЕННОЙ виртуальной машине и как на ней запустить скрипт? Какие настройки нужно сделать на виртуалке вин10 и непосредственно плагины для jenkins?

Comment: администратор уволился?

Comment: @aleksandrbarakin, нет) просто начинающий DevOps осваивает непрерывную доставку

Comment: тогда найдите основного администратора и спросите, как вам получить доступ к тому, что вам надо (не упоминайте при этом слово «jenkins» — оно роли не играет). а по поводу того, как, получив доступ к тому, что вам надо, выполнить на этом том чём надо скрипт powershell — смотрите в документации на сайте майкрософт (и при поиске тоже не упоминайте слова «jenkins» — оно и там никакой роли не играет).

Comment: @aleksandrbarakin, спасибо, сразу все заработало

Answer (score 0):

Важно чтобы виртуалки с Windows имели доступ к Jenkins master (а не наоборот). Нужно обеспечить это условие, а дальше по инстукции. 
На Windows инициатором подключения может являться slave. Slave может устанавливаться как служба.

Comment: спасибо за ответ